# Take focus away from tabs in ViewPager/TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, fragmentpageradapter

I am using ViewPager/TabLayout on Android TV, and I have 2 questions.

1) Currently, if I press DPAD_UP, the focus goes to the tabs, but the page does not actually change to the one corresponding to the focused tab until DPAD_CENTER is pressed. So, there is a difference between focused (shown as a grey box around the tab text) and selected (shown as an underline). I am wondering if it is possible to have whatever focused to be selected?

2) I have 3 tabs in my ViewPager where the fragment in tab1 needs to have focus in order to display things properly. When I switch from tab3 to tab1, the focus is not given to the fragment but stays with the tab. This causes my fragment to not display properly. I am wondering if there is a way to take focus away from the tab? I dug into the source code of ViewPager and TabLayout, and I know the focus is with TabView of TabLayout, but no matter what I try, I cannot take away the focus state of TabView (i.e. the grey box surrounding the tab text does not go away until I use DPAD_DOWN to "go down" to the fragment).

Tried 
`((ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(desiredPosition).clearFocus()` and it doesn't help. 
I don't want to use `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);`

```
// This is my viewpager activity class
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pager);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);

    // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            // Tried to clear focus of tab here, didn't help
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}


public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    // Returns total number of pages.
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for a particular page.
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new OneFragment; // This is the fragment that needs focus
            case 1:
                return new TwoFragment();
            case 2:
                return new ThreeFragment();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    // Returns the page title for the top indicator
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return "Fragment 1";
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return "Fragment 2";
        } else {
            return "Fragment 3";
        }
    }

}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeTab" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Have u tried request focus in one of the view inside the fragment?

Comment: I'd rather not requestFocus in the Fragment, as I don't have control over that Fragment, although I know if I requestFocus in the Fragment, problem 2 is solved.

Comment: For the first problem,  can't you use dispatch key event?

Comment: The problem is that I can't even use a focus change listener on the view that has the focus. Since the focus comes before the select, I will have to dispatch key event when the focus changes. Then, there comes the problem that I can't detect the focus.

Comment: My case is the opposite, I am not able to return focus back to Tabs. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

One liner solution :) . To suppress focus on Tablayout children views use the code fragment below assuming the tab is scrollable - i.e. tabs selection is scrolling by digipad:

```
tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);        
tabLayout.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

Comment: This does not work for me